# Redux and Redux-thunk

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

Im fairly new to redux, my question is. Do i need to use **middleWare** if i am using **Redux-thunk**. I need to make an **API** call and i want to know what i need in order to make that call using redux. I know how to do it without redux, but now i am building my E-commerce site and i need to use redux, but i am not very familiar with using thunk to fetch data. There are plenty of tutorials out there but non of them really helped or they are outdated. If someone came across a video feel free to post the link. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best course of action would be to go through the [official redux essentials tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts) which teaches modern redux and also has [a whole chapter on data fetching](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-5-async-logic) (but read it from the beginning!)